# Testing of existence of a repeated field in a protobuff message

Tags: python, unit-testing, protocol-buffers

I have a google protobuf message:

```
message Foo {
  required int bar = 1;
}
```

I know that in order to test the fields of message, we can use:

```
foo.bar = 1
assert foo.HasField("bar")
```

However "HasField" doesn't work for repeated field types.
How to test for existence of field for "repeated type" of fields?

```
message Foo {
  repeated int bar = 1;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like anyone really understood your question. You wanted to tell if a repeated field was not provided, vs if it was explicitly set to empty. I'm trying to achieve the same thing... did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to test the lenght of the repeated field:

```
assert len(foo.bar) == 0
```

Comment: but this only let me know that a field is added but not what field is it.

Comment: Yeah you have to know what field you have in your proto. Gje

Comment: The hasfield method is mostly there to test if the field as been set with some value

Comment: but the hasfield doesn't work for repeated kind of fields

Comment: Yes, it why you can test the lenght instead

Comment: wouldn't it `foo.bar_size()` suffice?

Answer (score 3):

The way to get around this is to enclose the repeated field in its own message.

```
message Foo {
  message Bars {
    repeated int bar = 1;
  }
  Bars bars = 1;
}
```

And then test for

```
foo.bars.SetInParent()
assert foo.HasField("bars")
```

That way you can tell if the repeated field wasn't set because there would be no reason to add the bars message to foo unless the intent was to add a bar.

Answer (score 1):

Given a `msg` variable with a message, you can print only repeated fields like  that. [from C# docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/reflection/field-descriptor#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_reflection_1_1_field_descriptor_1aa1b082401a59bd40071029ea46a50107)

```py
for descr in msg.DESCRIPTOR.fields:
    if descr.label == descr.LABEL_REPEATED:
        print(f'{descr.name} is repeated')
        for i, v_i in enumerate(getattr(msg, descr.name)):
            print(f'{i}:{v_i}')
```

Comment: I was exactly looking for how to check if a field is `repeated`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Repeated fields in .proto file doesn't support checking its existence via has_field_name().

Hence you can check the list size (because repeated field is a list) and make your business logic accordingly.

Example:

Consider below .proto file;

```
message XYZ {
  optional int64 raw_size = 1;

  // Repeated messages list
  message Abc {
    // The line.
    optional string line = 2;
  }

  // List of lines
  repeated Abc abc_list = 3;
}
```

Case 1:
Check if 'raw_size' exists in .proto file.

Solution: XYZ.has_raw_size()

Case 2: Check if 'abc_list' exists in .proto file.

Solution: XYZ.abc_list_size() > 0

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have said this would work:

```
assert len(foo.bar) == 0
```

but if you don't know the field name up front, say you're writing a utility that asserts an arbitrary field name in an arbitrary message has at least one element then this should do it:

```
assert len(getattr(msg, field_name))
```

where in your case `msg` is "foo" and `field_name` is "bar".